# How to code for a PHP user login with Oracle SQL?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, authentication

Ok so let me start off by saying I'm pretty noob still with PHP. Basically I'm trying to design a user registration and login system that queries the user data from an Oracle SQL database, and the only tutorials that are helpful to me are all for MYSQL. I was wondering if anyone had the time to help me with some PHP coding to get it working.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm trying to get a login page that sets a cookie to keep the users session until they logout. I have tried a few different variations and none of them work what so ever. I need it to work with the registration page I have below.

My code for the user registration at the moment, of which I'm fairly sure is pretty amateur is:

```
 <?php
 /* Set oracle user login and password info */
  $dbuser = "xxxxxxx";  /* your login */
  $dbpass = "xxxxxx";  /* your password */
  $db = "xxxxx"; 
  $connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db); 
  $salt = "plants";

  if (!$connect)  {
    echo "An error occurred connecting to the database"; 
    exit; 
  }


  // get the max ID in plants table and allocate $ID+1 for the new record
$max_id_stmt = "SELECT max(ID) FROM register_table";

// check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $max_id_stmt);
if(!$stmt) {
  echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
  exit;
}
OCIExecute($stmt);
$ID =0;

if(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
  $ID= OCIResult($stmt,1); //return the data from column 1
}else {
  echo "An error occurred in retrieving book id.\n";
  exit;
}
$ID++;


// Extract form data
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$address=$_REQUEST['address'];
global $salt;


// Create the SQL statement to add the data. Note: field value should be single quoted           
'' if VARCHAR2 type.
$sql = "INSERT INTO register_table VALUES ($ID, '$username', '$password', '$email',             
'$address', '$phone')";
$password = md5($salt.$password);
// Add the data to the database as a new record
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
if(!$stmt) {
echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
exit;
}
OCIExecute($stmt);
echo ("<p>Your registration has been successful!</p>
<p>User ID: $ID</P>
<p>Username: $username</p>
<p>Phone: $phone</p>
<p>Address: $address</p>


</p>")


?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi could you edit the question to include information about the specific error you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarifying the problem. I think you are perhaps confusing PHP's $_REQUEST variables with the $_SESSION variables. You'll need to establish a new session in order to maintain a user's session state, which in turn (by default, anyway) sets a cookie. You can establish a new session using standard PHP code either by using `session_start()` or by configuring PHP to establish a new session automatically.

Of course, doing so doesn't marry the current user to the registration data you're passing into the database via the above code; you would do so by associating the generated session ID with that user data. I suggest taking a look at [this page of the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for a quick primer.

Comment: Thank you for your time on the matter. I'm just really bad at explaining I think, but basically I need someones help to code a login and a registration page that uses an Oracle database to store the credentials. I'd be more than grateful if you'd have the time to help. Might be easier if we joined and IM session and posted the answer here at the end? Thanks again.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html would be great if it was written for Oracle SQL, but instead it's for MYSQL and I dont have enough expertise to convert it all.

Comment: I apologize but as much as I'd like to help, for a variety of reasons what you are asking isn't as trivial as it may seem. Consider checking out odesk, freelancer.com or similar if you're in need of a contract developer.